# (codeigniter) use jquery to call a controller to load a view inside a view

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

The scenario is like this. After adding a new comment. It will be appended after the previous comment.

Here's the steps of the theory that I have so far. **These codes do not have any attempt yet. This is just where the page will refresh after a new comment is added.**

```
1. type comment then press comment button
2. button will trigger ajax and get the values from the view
3. ajax will call controller and pass the values
4. controller will pass the values to the model and then store
5. controller will call a view and pass the newly added comment to this view 
note: this view only holds the css of a comment line
6. display this view after the previous comment
```

my codes so far

jquery:

```
$('.comments').on('click','.btn', function(event){
        event.preventDefault(); 
        var post_id = $(this).prev('.targetpost').val().trim();
        var comment = $(this).closest('.comments').find('textarea').val();
        if($(this).closest('.comments').find('textarea').val() == ''){
            alert("Comment cannot be blank");
        } 
        else 
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: BASE_URL+'classes/addcomment',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {post_id: post_id, comment: comment},
                async: false
        }); 
        //i'm planning to call the controller here then load the view after the previous comment so no more refreshing of page
        location.reload();
    }   
    });
```

controller:

```
public function addcomment(){
    $data = array(
        'user_id' => $this->user_id,
        'post_id' => $this->input->post('post_id'),
        'content' => $this->input->post('comment')
    );
    $this->Comment_model->addcomment($data);
    //load a view and pass the values of the new comment then load this view inside the view using jquery
}
```

comments section html

```
<div class="panel-body"><!-- the whole comment section -->
    <div class="tabbable-line">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs ">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#tab_1" data-toggle="tab">
                Comments </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_1">
                <!-- POST COMMENTS -->
                <div class="form-group prevcomments"><!-- comments are looped using php and are displayed here -->
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <ul class="media-list">
                            <li class="media">
                                <a class="pull-left" href="javascript:;">
                                <img class="todo-userpic" src="../../assets/admin/layout2/img/avatar8.jpg" width="27px" height="27px">
                                </a>
                                <div class="media-body todo-comment">
                                    <p class="todo-comment-head">
                                        <span class="todo-comment-username">John Doe</span> &nbsp; <span class="todo-comment-date">Jan 1, 1970 at 9:00am</span>
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="todo-text-color content">
                                        <?php echo nl2br($comment->content);?>  
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php }}} 
                    $this->load->view('pages/new_comment'); // where new comment will appear
                ?>                                                              
                <!-- END POST COMMENTS -->
                <!-- POST COMMENT FORM -->
                <form method="post" class="comments"><!-- where user types new comment -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <ul class="media-list">
                            <li class="media">
                                <img class="todo-userpic pull-left" src="../../assets/admin/layout2/img/avatar4.jpg" width="27px" height="27px">
                                <div class="media-body">
                                    <textarea></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $post->post_id;?>" class="targetpost">
                        <button type="submit" class="pull-right btn btn-sm btn-circle green-haze">Comment</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>
                <!-- END POST COMMENT FORM -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

One line comment html

```
<div class="form-group prevcomments">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul class="media-list">
            <li class="media">
                <a class="pull-left" href="javascript:;">
                <img class="todo-userpic" src="../../assets/admin/layout2/img/avatar8.jpg" width="27px" height="27px">
                </a>
                <div class="media-body todo-comment">
                    <p class="todo-comment-head">
                        <span class="todo-comment-username">John Doe New</span> &nbsp; <span class="todo-comment-date">Jan 1, 1970 at 9:00am</span>
                    </p>
                    <p class="todo-text-color content">
                        <?php echo "new comment is here"?>  
                    </p>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I know how to call a view inside a view. But I just do not know if it is possble to use jquery to call a controller to load a view inside a view.

Comment: in ajax success , you can load a view inside another view.

Comment: But the ajax will call a controller, then this controller will call a model and store the values. And after storing, the controller should load a view that will be appended. So is it possible to call a controller inside the ajax success?

Comment: dont call another controller, in the same controller, load the view you want.

Comment: refer the below answer.

Comment: best way is to maintain the structure of the page should be parent child like keep the child div invisible on default on ajax call create the child structure and append it to parent

Comment: What about putting this child div into another view page? Then just append it to the parent? Because the child div needs to get values from the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Only thing you have missed is success() in ajax.
In controller, `echo` the content which you want to load inside the main view. Then use `.html()` to insert the data inside a view.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: BASE_URL+'classes/addcomment',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {post_id: post_id, comment: comment},
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {//data will have what ever you echo'ed in controller
       alert(data)                
       $("#innerView").html(data);// you can add that html to your inner view

    }

});
```

Comment: I don't quite get this line `$("#innerView").html(data);`. `#innerView` will contain the new comment, right? Is this going to append after the previous comment? and this `html(data)`. Where am I supposed to specifiy the css of the new comment or is it still necessary?

Comment: with new comment you are appending to previous comments??

Comment: No need to specify css again, for that new comment ass necessary class and id.

Comment: Yes. Just like in facebook. Or here. When you add a new comment it will be appended after the comment you replied to.

Comment: You have a parent `div` for all your comments??

Comment: Yes. I've put the entire html of the comments section.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90415/discussion-between-niranjan-and-iamdevlin).